# How to convert FileStreamResult to IFormFile?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I change the size of the image with this code. But this method returns `FileStreamResult`. I want to convert `FileStreamResult`  to `IFromFile`. How can I do that?

Note: I am using [CoreCompat](https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat)  to change the image size.

```
public FileStreamResult ChangeSize(IFormFile file)  
{
    using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        Stream ms = new MemoryStream(img.Resize(100, 100).ToByteArray());

        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/jpg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should handle converting your FileStreamResult to a FormFile:

```
public IFormFile ReturnFormFile(FileStreamResult result)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        result.FileStream.CopyTo(ms);
        return new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       ms.Dispose();
       throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you opted not to use the `using` syntax?

Comment: "Using" is just syntax sugar for try/finally. If you look at the compiled ILASM code, "using" and "try/catch/finally" look very similar. The only difference, in this case, is I should have added a "Catch" to grab and handle an exception better.

Comment: @PoulBak Sort of, but either way you are just keeping it chilling on the heap like that, waiting for the GC to come and clean up your mess. By wrapping it with a "using," or telling it to Dispose will nullify it, and tell the GC when its ready to clean it up. Otherwise, it will just be sitting there eating memory for no reason, and if its a large byte aray that can be a mess.

Comment: @PoulBak No matter what, it still is good practice to get people in the habit of disposing of objects that inherit from IDisposable, so I don't know why you are bugging me about this. 2nd, run it all through a memory profiler and tell me if there is a diff. The GC doesn't automatically and instantly come and save the day, there are generations of objects that are waiting to be cleared from the heap. What if this is a recursive function, and we generate 20 memory streams with 1 gb of bytes, you want to clean that up ASAP.

Answer (score 7):

This works for the file but it doesn't appear to copy other data, such as the content type

```
public IFormFile GetFormFile(FileStreamResult fsr)
{
    using (var fs = fsr.FileStream)
    {
        file = new FormFile(fs, 0, fs.Length, "name", fsr.FileDownloadName);
    }
}
```