# How to assign image file to IFormFile Variable in ASP.net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, iformfile

How to assign image file to IFormFile Variable?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IFrameTesting.ViewModels
{
    public class ImageModelViewModels
    {
        [Display(Name ="Photo")]
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Converted Photo")]
        public IFormFile ConvertedIFormFilePhoto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have successfully converted and store to server side image. I want to get that image from server side and assign to variable **ConvertedIFormFilePhoto** how to acheive that?

Suppose there is image inside soultion Explore path is wwwroot/images/abc.jpg , I want to assign this abc.jpg  to variable **ConvertedIFormFilePhoto** how to achieve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165510/how-to-convert-filestreamresult-to-iformfile

Here is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Following codes works for me.**

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "images", "Screenshot (4)_225.png");           
using FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);            
IFormFile formFile = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null,Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
{
  Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
  ContentType = "image/*"
};
```

*** Here ContentType should be according to your file's MimeType.

Answer (score -1):

> Suppose there is image inside soultion Explore path is wwwroot/images/abc.jpg , I want to assign this abc.jpg to variable **ConvertedIFormFilePhoto** how to achieve it?

To achieve the requirement, you can try the following code snippet:

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, @"images\" + "abc.jpg");

using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead($"{filepath}"))
{
    var model = new ImageModelViewModels
    {
        ConvertedIFormFilePhoto = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
    };

    // ...
    // code logic here
}
```